# How to extract multi-volume archive within Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, zip, azure-storage

I have a multi-volume archive stored in Azure Blob Storage that is split into a series of zips titled like this:  Archive-Name.zip.001, Archive-Name.zip.002, etc. . . Archive-Name.zip.010.  Each file is 250 MB and contains hundreds of PDFs.

Currently we were trying to iterate through each archive part and extract the PDFs.  This works except when the past PDF in an archive has been split between two archive parts, ZipFile in C# is unable to process the split file and throws an exception.

We tried reading all the archive parts into a single MemoryStream and then extracting the files, however then we are finding the memory streams exceed 2GBs  which is the limit - so this method does not work either.

It is not feasible to download the archive into a machines memory, extract, then upload the PDFs to a new file.  The extraction needs to be done in Azure where the program will run.

This is the code we are currently using - it is unable to handle PDFs split between two archive parts.

```
 public static void UnzipTaxForms(TextWriter log, string type, string fiscalYear)
    {
        var folderName = "folderName";
        var outPutContainer = GetContainer("containerName");
        CreateIfNotExists(outPutContainer);
        var fileItems = ListFileItems(folderName);

        fileItems = fileItems.Where(i => i.Name.Contains(".zip")).ToList();

        foreach (var file in fileItems)
        {
            using (var ziped = ZipFile.Read(GetMemoryStreamFromFile(folderName, file.Name)))
            {
                foreach (var zipEntry in ziped)
                {
                    using (var outPutStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        zipEntry.Extract(outPutStream);
                        var blockblob = outPutContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(zipEntry.FileName);
                        outPutStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        blockblob.UploadFromStream(outPutStream);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Another note.  We are unable to change the way the multi-volume archive is generated.  Any help would be appreciated.